# Equivalent tool to Copy raster using ArcCatalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog

I am using ArcGIS 10.8.

It take less than 3 seconds to copy raster (25k*30k cells) from one file geodatabase to another manually (Copy-Paste).

When I use Copy Raster tool it takes much-much longer.

What tool shall I use to perform this operation faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested but I think it should work using the [Copy](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy.htm) tool which:

> Makes a copy of the input data.

```
import arcpy 
arpy.env.workspace = r"C:\temp\test.gdb"    
arcpy.Copy_management("testRaster1","testRaster2)
```